# Threads in a daemon are not running

Tags: linux, multithreading, daemon

I have written a multi-threaded process which was running without any issues when it was not a daemon.

The moment I made it a daemon, all the threads stopped running, only the code in the main() function infinite loop is running.

I did a fork() and then setsid() to make it a daemon.

Need help finding the cause.

Comment: You need to make it a daemon and **then** launch all the threads, only in this order.